# Derivative of Fresnel integral function with functional limits

Tags: derivatives, fresnel-integrals

How do I find a derivative (with respect to $x$) of a Fresnel integral function with functional limits:
$$f(x)=\int_{\sin^2(x^2)}^{e^{2x}}\sin(z^2)\,dz.$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @RobertZ, looks like this is exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: @RobertZ : The Leibniz integral rule assumes something inside the integral, rather than only the bounds, depends on $x.$ This present problem can be done by using only the chain rule and the fundamental theorem; thus with only those things that are taught in the standard freshman course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that in general

$$f(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}g(u) \,du\implies f'(x)=g(b(x))\cdot b'(x)-g(a(x))\cdot a'(x)$$